# How to create a project under https://github.com/ros2/?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are 81 projects under https://github.com/ros2/ already, may I know if I'd like to contribute new projects and create new projects under this structure, is there any process to follow?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/279193/how-to-create-a-project-under-https://github.com/ros2/?/) by [cathyshen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33203/cathyshen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2018-01-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ROS team at OSRF maintains the ros2 organization on github, but there's nothing that requires ROS2 projects to be part of the ros2 organization.

If you have a very compelling project idea you may be able to convince the ROS team to create the project for you, but you should probably create the project under your own github account and then if it becomes very popular ask to have it moved to the ros2 organization.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-01-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cathyshen](https://answers.ros.org/users/33203/cathyshen/) on 2018-01-09**:
Noted and thanks for your answer!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-01-09**:
@cathyshen: could I ask you to please mark the question as answered by ticking the checkmark to the left of @ahendrix's answer? Thanks.